# How do I remove all the same integers from an arraylist of objects?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList <Players> players = new ArrayList();`

In which I have a method where I have set integers to them. Using players.get(i).getWincounter;

I can find their specific integers, however now I want to remove all the lowest integers. 
ex (2,1,1,1) 1s are the lowest however i only remove 1 of them, not all.

This is what I have tired:

```
int current = 0;
int min = 900;
// ArrayList<Integer> min = new ArrayList <Integer>();
if (players.size() >= 2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
        current = players.get(i).getWinCounter();
        if (current < min) {
            min = current;
        }
    }
    // System.out.println(min);
    removePlayer(players, min);
    checkLeftPlayers(players);
}
```

RemovePlayer method contains the following:

```
public void removePlayer(ArrayList<Player> players, int min) {
    System.out.println(min);
    for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
        if (players.get(i).getWinCounter() == min) {
            players.remove(players.get(i));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("====================================");
    System.out.println("NEW STAGE");
    checkLeftPlayers(players);
}
```

There is something wrong with my remove method and I can't figure out what. Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you want to be able to understand your own code, and if you want us to be able to understand it, indent it correctly. Your IDE can format it with a single keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Every time you remove an element from the `ArrayList`, the index changes (so the next element which was `i + 1` is now `i`), you then increment `i` which means you skip over it

Comment: Use an Iterator to iterate through the list, and use the iteratr's remove method to remove the current element. or simpler, use the removeIf() method.

Comment: You can also use a `while()` loop and increment the loop counter in the `else` part of this condition `if (players.get(i).getWinCounter() == min)` fails. So that the loop counter will not increase if any item get removed.